# BC transmission line data into google earth?

Tags: google-earth-pro

When I try to look the transmission line data into Google Earth. I can not see the transmission lines.

How can I view the transmission lines in Google Earth?

The data is at:
https://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset/bc-transmission-lines/resource/3679fd70-fc60-4d6f-8079-13cd8c20c02d

I have version 7.3.1 of Google Earth Pro.

Comment: the wms (via google earth network link is malformed) so download the shapefile in lat/lng and load it into google earth pro

Comment: It works OK, you just need to zoom-in quite a bit.